# How to store initial prop state in function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to pass some props to a third-party drawing library, but I need to pass only the *initial* value of the prop. I've made a wrapper component which captures the initial props in state, and then passes them to the third-party component.

This works, but since `setZoom` and `setCenter` aren't used, it feels like an anti-pattern:

```js
function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
  const [initialZoom, setInitialZoom] = useState(zoom);
  const [initialCenter, setInitialCenter] = useState(center);

  return <ThirdParty zoom={initialZoom} center={initialCenter} />
}
```

I tried `useMemo` but eslint also warned about missing dependencies:

> React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'zoom'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```js
function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
  const initialZoom = useMemo(() => zoom, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const initialCenter = useMemo(() => center, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return <ThirdParty zoom={initialZoom} center={initialCenter} />
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this? Or is it so non-standard that just ignoring the eslint warnings on the `useMemo` example is the best option?

Comment: It seems like always using the `center` and `zoom` instead of making a new state would give you the right answer. But also, you don't need to use `setZoom` or `setIntialCenter` you can just put `const [initialZoom] = useState(zoom)`. No need to even define `setInitialZoom`. -- just remember that every time zoom changes, you'll create a new version of the initial state.

Comment: You could achieve this using a ref: `const initialZoom = useRef(zoom).current` - the value of the ref will be maintained during re-renders so any updates to `Wrapper` won't modify the value. Example https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-grothendieck-2ymhkw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @JakeAve the center and zoom props change regularly, so that's why I can't use them directly.

Comment: @Dan good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This works, but since setZoom and setCenter aren't used, it feels like
> an anti-pattern:
>
> ```
> function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
>   const [initialZoom, setInitialZoom] = useState(zoom);
>   const [initialCenter, setInitialCenter] = useState(center);
>
>   return <ThirdParty zoom={initialZoom} center={initialCenter} />
> }
> ```

This isn't so much anti-pattern as much as it is just unused declarations. You *don't need to* destructure the state updater function. Just set the initial value and don't ever update it.

```
function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
  const [initial] = useState({ center, zoom });

  return <ThirdParty zoom={initial.zoom} center={initial.center} />
}
```

> I tried useMemo but eslint also warned about missing dependencies:
>
> > React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'zoom'. Either include it
> > or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
> ```
> function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
>   const initialZoom = useMemo(() => zoom, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>   const initialCenter = useMemo(() => center, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
>   return <ThirdParty zoom={initialZoom} center={initialCenter} />
> }
> ```

This is also a valid use case, using an empty dependency array to run the hook once on component mount, ***but*** as you see, the react hook linting rules will complain about a possible missing dependency.

Other alternatives include:

- Using a React ref to hold the initial values:

  ```
  function Wrapper({ center, zoom }) {
    const initialRef = useRef({ center, zoom });

    return <ThirdParty zoom={initialRef.zoom} center={initialRef.center} />
  }
  ```

Instead of a wrapper component you may want a Higher Order Component to just memoize the initial `props` value.

Example:

```
const withMemoizedInitialProps = Component => props => {
  const initialPropsRef = useRef(props);
  return <Component {...initialPropsRef.current} />
};
```

...

```
const DecoratedThirdParty = withMemoizedInitialProps(ThirdParty);
```

...

```
<DecoratedThirdParty zoom={zoom} center={center} />
```

[image: Edit how-to-store-initial-prop-state-in-function-component]